# Difference between developing an ASP.NET site and web design using HTML and css

Tags: html, asp.net

I was wondering what's the difference between an ASP.NET site and developing a site with Notepad++ ?

I know that ASP.NET can work with servers and C# and things. Also I know that you can create an HTML file in Visual Studio so you can do that instead of Notepad++.

Also I know that with ASP.NET you can have Master Pages but not with an HTML file and Master Pages are much easier than copy and past on a lot of different sites.

Also can you develop a simple site with ASP.NET, no servers, just a site for people to get a contact detail and find out about your company? Because I really like master pages.

Comment: ASP.NET uses the server to render the content - other than that it's all HTML and CSS.

Comment: "difference between an asp.net site and developing a site with notepad++" — None. You can write ASP.NET code using Notepad++.

Comment: Thanks for the comeback, I know it was a bit of a silly question, but now I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is showing a complete lack of knowledge on this stuff. Before going to a job interview, you should go through some tutorials (you can find plenty on YouTube) and/or read some books on web site development. Otherwise I fear your interviewer will think something along the lines of "this guy just read a bunch of computer terms online and strung them together without understanding any of them". I know that may sound harsh, but I want to make sure you go into your interview prepared.

ASP.NET uses server side code to generate output. At the end of the day, it's just serving up HTML, CSS, JavaScript etc to the client. You can create "plain" HTML sites (non ASP.NET sites) with Visual Studio, or you can write the code for ASP.NET sites with Notepad (or event a command line text editor). At some point, though ASP.NET sites will need to be compiled before they can be served to a client via a web server.

No, you can't build a site with ASP.NET and run it without a server. You must have a server. Wikipedia has a nice entry on the [Client-Server model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model).

Comment: Thanks for the criticism, and its not to harsh at all, I got the job and there's a site we are going to develop but he doesn't want it to be asp, so we just added html pages, so we can us master pages that's why I asked as I was a little confused. I have used asp to do 2 sites, so I do know a little. so there's no difference shweet, thank to everyone for the advice and thanks Mason for your criticism.

Comment: @JodyStocks You can't use Master Pages without ASP.NET. Instead you can use [Server Side Includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) or you can dynamically load sections of the page using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) techniques. Or if you go with another server side framework such as [node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) or [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), they probably have some equivalents to ASP.NET Master Pages (though I wouldn't know about them).

Comment: We are trying to use something called shtml, which I have never heard of before, and that to has the include tag

Comment: @JodyStocks If you read the Server Side Includes link I included above, it describes what the .shtml files are for.